# Webpack 2 with angular 2 and asp.net mvc cshtml as template

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, razor, webpack-2

I've a project running with Angular 2 and webpack 2 but currently I load all my templates directly into the js file with no addional template loading from the server. That works great.

```
@Component({
selector: 'logmonitor',
styleUrls: [ './logmonitor.component.less' ],
templateUrl: './logmonitor.component.html'
}) ...
```

but I need to load only some Templates from a cshtml view and the views should only get loaded with an extra server request when I open these views.

I've created a simple cshtml view in my views folder an I can directly "show" it when typing the right controller/action into the url. That "works"

but I've tried to set this to get the Template loaded

```
@Component({
  selector: 'testView',
  templateUrl: 'Logviewer/TestLogview',
}) ...
```

but webpack will not compile the view it gives a error

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './Logviewer/TestLogview' in 'C:\SourceControl\WebLogViewer\App\Views\LogViewer'
```

thats right the file is daved in

```
C:\SourceControl\WebLogViewer\Views\LogViewer
```

but I don't want that webpack tries to resolve this url, angular itself need to call this url when the view gets loaded. I've thought webpack will not try to load the cshtml file when I don't write the "./" in front of the file name, but thats not working. Is there a solution how I can prevent webpack from parsing all templateUrl ?

thats my current Loader for html files, but this should not parse the string because there is not .html at the end :-/

```
{
   test: /\.html$/,
   use: ['raw-loader'],
   exclude: [helpers.root('App/index.html')]
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find a working example in this repo.
https://github.com/timdows/webpages/tree/master/Angular2RazorViews

The key is lazy loading and

```
angular2-load-children-loader
```

in loading the ts template dependencies